# how to rotate an img in the html page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I just use the jquery rotate plug-in to accomplish my `img` rotation,but I find it's not perfect.It just rotate the `img`,but I want the parent div to resize with the rotating.
U know ,if the width and the height are different,it will not show all the img after the rotation,or it will cover other tag. So if there is other method helping me to rotate the img and change the div's width and height automatically.

Comment: Would rotating the `div` not fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

```
div
{
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: +1 despite the fact you cited w3schools.com

Comment: thanks a lot,but the rotated div will cover the tags behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) .

This is awesome jquery plugin to rotate image.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a plugin you can try jQuery.

```
$(function() {
var $item_to_rotate = $('#item_to_rotate');
var $parent_div = $('parent_div');
rotate(0);
function rotate(degree) {

    $item_to_rotate.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    $item_to_rotate.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    $parent_div.css({'width':'auto', 'height':'auto'})
    setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },5);
}
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot and I'll have a try